# Class method returning None in python

Tags: python, class, oop, binary-search-tree

I have a simple class to traverse a binary tree. I want to store the values of the nodes in arr and return them. The values are being appended to the array as expected but when I am returning the arr, it is being returned as None. I am new to Object-oriented programming with python, please help me with details.

```
class Solution:
    def inorder(self, head , arr):
        if head:
            self.inorder(head.left , arr)
            arr.append(head.val)
            self.inorder(head.right, arr)
        else:
            print(arr)
            return arr
    def check(self, root: TreeNode) -> bool:
        arr = []
        arr = self.inorder(root , [])
        print(arr)
```

Comment: Your `if head:` case doesn't return anything, and thus by default in python, `None` is returned.

Comment: Just think about if `if head` is `True`. You're not returning anything. The `else` statement would never run in that case. What are you expecting to happen, from a design standpoint?

Comment: You are updating `arr` in place: `self.inorder(root, arr)`.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including complete code, expected output, and actual output. BTW, `arr = []` is pointless cause you reassign `arr` in the next line.